# Python SQLITE3 UPDATE gives 'None' as the output

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

My apologies if a similar question has been answered earlier, but I'm a beginner at SQLITE3 (A day old) and I really can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

My Table (3 columns namely, {A1, A2, W}):

**A1 A2 W**
12 67 0
15 01 0

```
Code:

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/advaitbalaji/Desktop/p.txt', sep = '\t', header = 0)
df.head()
connex = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cur = connex.cursor()
df.to_sql(name = 'database', con = connex, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
cur.execute("SELECT Weights FROM database WHERE A1 = 12 AND A2 = 67")
k = cur.fetchone()
print(k)
cur.execute("UPDATE database SET W = W + 1 WHERE A1 = 12 AND 2 = 67")
k = cur.fetchone()
print(k)
connex.commit()


Output:  
 (0,)  
 None
```

I even made the following changes to the code, but the output remains the same:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Weights FROM database WHERE A1 = 12 AND A2 = 67")
k = cur.fetchone()
print(k)
cur.execute("UPDATE database SET W = ? WHERE A1 = 12 AND A2 = 67",(k[0]+1,))
k = cur.fetchone()
print(k)
connex.commit()

Output:
 (0,)
 None
```

I can't seem to figure out why my output isn't as follows:

```
Desired Output:
(0,)
(1,)
```

Comment: In some of it you're calling it W, others you're calling it Weights, could that be a problem?

Comment: @Zooby Ah! The 'Weights' is a typo. The problem persisted even with W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the cursor to execute an update, to return a result tuple, you'll need to have the cursor execute a select query once again. If you copy the same conditions for the same select clause as at the start, it should return the expected results.

```
cur.execute("SELECT W FROM database WHERE A1 = 12 AND A2 = 67")
k = cur.fetchone()
print(k)
cur.execute("UPDATE database SET W = ? WHERE A1 = 12 AND A2 = 67",(k[0]+1,))
cur.execute("SELECT W FROM database WHERE A1 = 12 AND A2 = 67")
k = cur.fetchone()
print(k)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Looks like my concepts aren't that clear yet :P